# Target URL's with a .html extention, remove the extension and add a trialing slash

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I'm trying to overwrite only the URLs that end in .html to have the extension removed and then add a trailing slash to the end.

This should result in something like `foo.com/bar.html` to `foo.com/bar/` and still retrieve the html file in the root of the directories.

The below code is working but it can no longer find the .html file to load.

This is on WordPress and I'm thinking this is very important to understand to make this work correctly.

```html
#test (does what it needs to but does not grab the file)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ $1.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ $1_$2.html [L]
# end test
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry! Simple copy and paste error on `RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ $1.php` needs to be `RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ $1.html`

```html
#test (does what it needs to but does not grab the file)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ $1.php # Obviously needs to be .html, not .php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ $1_$2.html [L]
# end test
```